# Determine $f(y_1, y_2)$ precisely.

Tags: probability-distributions

Context of the problem:

Continuous bivariate random variable $(Y_1, Y_2)$ has the uniform density $f(y_1, y_2)$ on support S = $(y_1, y_2) \leq 1-y_1^2, y_1 \leq 0, y_2 \leq 0$. Thus, $f(y_1, y_2)$ has a positive constant value on S and value 0 elsewhere.

The question says "Determine $f(y_1, y_2)$ precisely" but doesn't ask for a specific value. Is this asking for the value of the integral across all of [0,1] where the function is defined?

Comment: What does it mean that the support $S = (y_1,y_2) \leq 1 - y_1^2$?

Comment: It is still unclear what the support is here. If $f$ being uniform means maybe that it is constant. If $f\equiv c$
on $S$ then you need $1=\int_{S}f\left(y_{1},y_{2}\right)dy_{1}dy_{2}=c\lambda\left(S\right)$.
Here $\lambda\left(S\right)$ stands for the Lebesgue-measure of $S$.
If $S$ (hence $\lambda\left(S\right)$) is known then based on this equality
you can determine $c$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f\left(y_{1},y_{2}\right)$ is constant on support $S\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$
and takes constant value $c$ there, then $1=\int\int f\left(y_{1},y_{2}\right)dy_{1}dy_{2}=c\lambda\left(S\right)$
where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

This way you find $c=\lambda\left(S\right)^{-1}$ and $f$ is determined
precisely.